# AvalonDock 2.0 LayoutRoot.LeftSide Width

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I want to set the default width of `LayoutRoot.LeftSide`. When I disable the autohide of my LayoutAnchorable and pin it to the left side of the window, it's width is very small and the content is not readable. how can I pin a LayoutAnchorable to the left side without loosing its previous with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears it's a bug that will be fixed in upcoming v2.8

[Described here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/639118)